# Cordova app installation crashes on android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Today I am trying to make a cordova app out of my existing website.
This seems to be pretty easy but there are some errors for me.

After installing everything and creating a new cordova project I only added this line in the `index.js`:

```
window.location = "http://myHomePage.net";
```

This should be enough for using your hosted website in a cordova android app.

And it really seems to work on my emulator but when I build the release for the app with:

```
cordova build --release android
```

and try to install the output apk my phone says:

`app was not installed`

How is this possible and does somebody know this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is don't use `cordova build --release android`!

`cordova build android` works.